# Contact Form 7 - Need Assistance with Shortcode and Value

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I am creating a form using the contact form 7 plugin where the user is required to select colors by clicking the checkboxes. **I have altered the style of the checkbox.** When the user submits the form, I need to receive the colors selected by the user.

When I use the standard checkbox, I receive the colors perfectly via email.

With the altered checkbox style, I don't receive the colors.

Where within the HTML, should I insert the shortcode provided by contact form 7 to receive the colors selected via email?

**The HTML code is as under**

```
<label class="container" for="red">
    <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="red">
    <span class="checkmark red"></span>
</label>
```

**The shortcode I want to insert is**

```
[checkbox checkbox-red value "Red,"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing the value that you're expecting to see when using your html markup is that it's not part of the Contact Form fields.

You can try the below:

```
<label class="container" for="checkbox-red">
    [checkbox checkbox-red id:red class:single-check value "Red,"]
    <span class="checkmark red"></span>
</label>
```

You can also find more information here [Contact Form 7 Documentation](https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/)